# What is core file in Debian?

Tags: debian, core-dump

My Debian laptop became unresponsive and I decided to force poweroff. After booting, I found a `core` file in my home directory. What is it and how can I use it? I guess that it is some sort of memory dump for debugging. I tried `gdb core`, but it says that the file format is not recognised.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s a core dump; `file` will tell you which executable it corresponds to, and then you can analyse it using

```
gdb /path/to/program /path/to/core
```

You might need to install debug packages to get the corresponding symbols; to do this, enable the relevant repository by running the following as root:

```
echo deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-debug buster-debug main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debug.list
apt update
```

The install `debian-goodies` and use `find-dbgsym-packages` to find the relevant packages:

```
apt install debian-goodies
apt install $(find-dbgsym-packages /path/to/program)
```